# create nested class in runtime

Tags: c#, reflection, reflection.emit

i have a xml file with this structure

```
<graph>
    <id>0</id>
    <name>John</name>
    <link>http://test.com</link>
</graph>
<graph>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>Roger</name>
    <link>http://test2.com</link>
</graph>
```

i want use Reflection.Emit class for create two class
first:

```
class A {
     int id;
     string name;
     string link
}
```

second:

```
Class B{
      List<A> graphs;
}
```

i read this paper ([Introduction to Creating Dynamic Types with Reflection.Emit](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13337/Introduction-to-Creating-Dynamic-Types-with-Reflec)) and can create class A in runtime but the problem is using this (A) in another runtime class(B) and also have a List of A.

```
MyClassBuilder MCB=new MyClassBuilder("A");
var myclass = MCB.CreateObject(new string[3] { "id", "name", "link" }, new Type[3] { typeof(int), typeof(string), typeof(string) });
Type TP = myclass.GetType();
MyClassBuilder MCB1=new MyClassBuilder("B");
//Here is my confusion typeof(List<TP>) ?????? Error Ocurred
var myclass2 = MCB1.CreateObject(new string[1] {"graphs"}, new Type[1]{typeof(List<TP>)});
//set value of class A and work
object tp = Activator.CreateInstance(TP);
TP.GetProperty("id").SetValue(tp,0);
TP.GetProperty("name").SetValue(tp,"Joh");
TP.GetProperty("link").SetValue(tp,"http://test.com");

//set value of class B ??????
//add tp in graphs
```

Comment: `typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(TP)`

Comment: thanks @PetSerAl for quick reply, the first problem gone, do you have any idea for add tp varible into graphs.

Comment: You can create list instance with `Activator.CreateInstance`, as now you know right type, and you can call `Add` method to add elements to that list.

Comment: Maybe you can use Roslyn to generate C# code. That seems like an easier route.